# How do I automatically Set MDCard height

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I want to set `mdcard height` such that it fits `mdlabel`, perhabs without me manually setting mdcard size.
please how do I do this.. Thanks in Advance..

For better understanding here's a sample code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: '10dp', '15dp'
            spacing: '15dp'

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 280, 200
                MDLabel:
                    markup: True
                    padding: [15, 15]
                    text:
                        '''
                        [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                        If mdlabel text becomes too many to fit into the specified mdcard size,\n
                        the text overslaps other things closeby..\n
                        So my question: How do I set MDCard height to automatically\n
                        adjusts accordingly to the height/size of widgets inside of it.\n
                        Thanks in Advance!!
                        '''

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 280, 200
                MDLabel:
                    markup: True
                    padding: [15, 15]
                    text:
                        '''
                        [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                        If mdlabel text becomes too many to fit into the specified mdcard size,\n
                        the text overslaps other things closeby..\n
                        So my question: How do I set MDCard height to automatically\n
                        adjusts accordingly to the height/size of widgets inside of it.\n
                        Thanks in Advance!!
                        '''



"""


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

just like the code above, If mdlabel text becomes too many to fit into the specified mdcard size, the text overslaps other things closeby..
So my question: How do I set MDCard height to automatically adjusts accordingly to the height/size of widgets inside of it.
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `height` of the `MDCard` to be the same as the `height` of the `MDLabel`, but you must allow the `MDLabel` to adjust to the size of its `text`. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does that:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: '10dp', '15dp'
            spacing: '15dp'

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                # size: 280, 200
                height: label1.height
                MDLabel:
                    id: label1
                    markup: True
                    padding: [15, 15]
                    text:
                        '''
                        [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                        If mdlabel text becomes too many to fit into the specified mdcard size,\n
                        the text overslaps other things closeby..\n
                        So my question: How do I set MDCard height to automatically\n
                        adjusts accordingly to the height/size of widgets inside of it.\n
                        Thanks in Advance!!
                        '''
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]

            MDCard:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, None
                # size: 280, 200
                height: label2.height
                MDLabel:
                    id: label2
                    markup: True
                    padding: [15, 15]
                    text:
                        '''
                        [size=25][b]Ford[/b][/size]
                        If mdlabel text becomes too many to fit into the specified mdcard size,\n
                        the text overslaps other things closeby..\n
                        So my question: How do I set MDCard height to automatically\n
                        adjusts accordingly to the height/size of widgets inside of it.\n
                        Thanks in Advance!!
                        '''
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1] + 2*self.padding[1]
```